# How to programmatically display an image field in Drupal 7 + default value when needed

Tags: entities

I've used `field_view_field` to display an image field for a specific entity in Drupal. The problem is when that entity doesn't have any value for field. I expect `field_view_field` to display the default image for field but it doesn't load default value of the field.

How can I do this?

Comment: can you post the code you have that isn't working properly?

Comment: I would start debugging from image_field_prepare_view() where it handles default images.

Comment: My code was:      $user_pic = drupal_render(
        field_view_field('user', $user_loaded, 'field_profile_photo', 
          array(
            'label' => 'hidden',
            'settings' => array(
              'image_style' => '170_170'
            )
          )));

Comment: Can you post it in your question instead of the comment? It's easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

field_view_field is a correct function to use if you want to display node image (if provided) or default (attached to field settings) if not.

```
$node = node_load($nid);
print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_image')));
```

Comment: According to the question they are already doing this but it isn't showing the default image when it should be.

Comment: I know and I'm surprised. Even checked if it works on local copy of D7 and everything seems to be ok. @Sebto - are you sure that default image is correctly loaded into field settings form and correctly configured in Manage Display -> Default? Try to dpm field_view_field for random node **with** image and other one **without** image (with default image uploaded).

Answer (score 0):

In our case we have two set of images

1. Default image
2. another is node specific image

i created two block in views in the **first view get the default image it will always have the default image**

and in the **second block render the image if the image field is empty render the whole default block there**, below is the sample code

in views block 2 select the image field in the view and exclude it from display

in views global php add the code below

```
<?php
    $banner = isset($data->field_field_banner)? $data->field_field_banner : '';
    if(!empty($banner)){
      print drupal_render($banner);
    }else{
          print render_view_block_for_noresult('view_name','block_name');
    }
?>


/* function to render default view blocks if no banner is present */
function render_view_block_for_noresult($view_name='',$block_name=''){
        $view = views_get_view($view_name);
        if(isset($view) && !empty($view))
            return $view->preview($block_name);
}
```

this will help you to print the image and get the default image printed in the view.

Comment: 2 views to display one image seems like overkill. Also you should be able to do this without custom code by putting one view in the empty text setting of the first view so that if the first view returns no results the view in the empty text displays.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I find a solution for my problem. If there aren't any value for field, it retrieves field instance information then load default image of field and display it.

```
       $user_loaded = user_load($uid);
if ($user_loaded->field_profile_photo[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]) {
  $user_pic = drupal_render(
    field_view_field('user', $user_loaded, 'field_profile_photo', 
      array(
        'label' => 'hidden',
        'settings' => array(
          'image_style' => '170_170'
        )
      )));
}
else {
  $instance = field_info_instance('user', 'field_profile_photo','user');
  $user_loaded->field_profile_photo[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = (array)file_load($instance['settings']['default_image']);
  $user_pic = drupal_render(
    field_view_field('user', $user_loaded, 'field_profile_photo', 
      array(
        'label' => 'hidden',
        'settings' => array(
          'image_style' => '170_170'
        )
      )));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to use a field instance's default image as a fallback when the individual image field itself is empty.

To briefly explain the concept, use [field_get_items()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_get_items/7.x) to attempt to get the image attached to the entity (e.g. node, user, taxonomy_term, ...), then fallback to [field_info_instance()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7.x) if an image has not been uploaded.

Once an image is available to work with, set the `$file` variable to the image reference, which will get rendered after calling [field_view_value()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7.x).

```
$field_image = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image');

if (!empty($field_image)) {
  $file = $field_image[0];
}
else {
  $info = field_info_instance('node', 'field_image', 'blog');

  if (!empty($info) && $info['settings']['default_image'] > 0) {
    $default_image_fid = $info['settings']['default_image'];

    $file = (array) file_load($default_image_fid);
  }
}

if ($file) {
  $image = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_image', $file, array(
    'type' => 'image',
    'settings' => array(
      'image_style' => NULL,
    ),
  ));

  print render($image);
}
```

All of this logic could be wrapped up into a helper function or simply used wherever needed.